# Symfony2 security.yml correct configuration

Tags: symfony

Im new to symfony2 version 3.0 and Im trying to create a login form. But I'm stuck in security.yml configuration and I dont know whats going on. Im been searching in google for 3 hours but no luck. Hope you can help me. So far here is my code.

```
security:
  encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt

  providers:
    db_provider:
      entity:
        class: AppBundle:User
        property: username

  firewalls:
    login_area:
      pattern: ^/user/login$
      security: false

    secured_area:
      pattern: ^/admin
      anonymous: ~
      form_login:
        login_path: user/login
        check_path: user/login-check
        always_use_default_target_path: true
        default_target_path: /admin
        provider: db_provider
```

Every time I go to http://localhost:8000/admin it gives me this error

```
The check_path "user/login-check" for login method "form_login" is not matched by the firewall pattern "^/admin".


Invalid configuration for path "security.firewalls.secured_area": The check_path "user/login-check" for login method "form_login" is not matched by the firewall pattern "^/admin".
```

Comment: Why security: and encoders: has the same vertical alignment?

Comment: no the alignment is correct in my file, it just happen the alignment was moved after I copied it here

Comment: response told that logic-check should start from admin like admin/login-check instea of user/login-check. Can you try this one with changing related routing?

Comment: Hi @Rinat, I tried to change the check_path just like you said. I also change the pattern to admin/* and its working fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `login_check` path must be covered by one of firewalls.

```
firewalls:
    login_area:
       pattern: ^/admin/user/login$
       security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/admin
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/user/login
            check_path: /admin/user/login-check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /admin
            provider: db_provider

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/user/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Note from [symfony.com docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#be-sure-check-path-is-behind-a-firewall):

> Make sure that your check_path URL (e.g. /login) is behind the
>   firewall you're using for your form login (in this example, the single
>   firewall matches all URLs, including /login). If /login doesn't match
>   any firewall, you'll receive a Unable to find the controller for path
>   "/login" exception.